# is there a Java's bufferstrategy equivalent in android?

Tags: java, android

BufferStrategy from java api:

`an application draws to a single back buffer and then moves the contents to the front
 (display) in a single step, either by copying the data or moving the video pointer. Moving
 the video pointer exchanges the buffers so that the first buffer drawn becomes the front
 buffer, or what is currently displayed on the device;`

I'm looking for something like Java's `BufferStrategy` to put in my android app to smooth the movement of some animation. What is the equivalent? At the moment the animation looks very poor.
If such an equivalent doesn't exist, what is the correct way of doing smooth animations?

Comment: You might wanna google search for reto meirer's dev bytes and similar series from other google android dev's. Theres a complete series on animation and animating view translations.